# webapi entity frameworks - best way to return nested classes where

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Based on this diagram using webapi entity frameworks, what would be the best way to say, return me all Menus.text.... where AspNetUsers.Username = xxxx.

I think I need to start with a MenusController, and say return Menus(Include Permissions, include groups, include AspNetUsers, where username = x.

Is that the best way?

[image: sql diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need text field of menu, not use include, better is use projection to load desired fields as following:

```
var menuTextList = db.Users.Where(e=> e.Username = "xxxx")
               .Select(e=> e.Group)
               .SelectMany(e=> e.Permissions)
               .Select(e=> e.Menu)
               .Select(e=> e.text)
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

and for all fields in menus, as following:

```
var munuList = db.Users.Where(e=> e.Username = "xxxx")
               .Select(e=> e.Group)
               .SelectMany(e=> e.Permissions)
               .Select(e=> e.Menu)
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

Comment: this worked perfectly!  thanks for pointing me in the right direction